# Vue-test-utils | Jest: How to handle dependencies?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

**THE SITUATION:**

I am implementing unit-testing in my Vue app, using vue-test-utils with Jest configuration.

When I am testing simple components everything is fine. But when I am testing components that import other dependencies, the test fails.

**CONFIGURATION:**

Vue version: `2.5.17` 
@vue/test-utils: `1.0.0-beta.20` 
cli-plugin-unit-jest: `3.0.3` 
babel-jest: `23.0.1`

**THE ERROR MESSAGE:**

The exact error message depends on which dependency I am importing.

For example with [epic-spinners](https://github.com/epicmaxco/epic-spinners) the error is:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

[image]

With [vue-radial-progress](https://github.com/wyzant-dev/vue-radial-progress) the error is:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

[image]

**HOW TO REPRODUCE:**

- Make a fresh install of vue (with Jest as unit testing suite)
- Run the example test, it should pass
- Install a dependency (for example: `npm install --save epic-spinners`)
- Import the dependency inside the HelloWorld component
- Run the test again (without changing anything)

If I do these steps, the test fails with the above error message.

**THE QUESTION:**

How can I handle dependencies import in vue-test-utils / Jest ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was that some modules may not be compiled correctly.

The solution is to use the [transformIgnorePatterns](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#transformignorepatterns-array-string) property of the Jest settings. That is, from the docs:

> An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all source
>   file paths before transformation. If the test path matches any of the
>   patterns, it will not be transformed.

In my case, this is how I have solved the issue:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: [
  "node_modules/(?!epic-spinners|vue-radial-progress)"
],
```

**EDIT:**

This is my jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'jsx',
    'json',
    'vue'
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/(?!epic-spinners|vue-radial-progress)"
    // "node_modules/(?!epic-spinners)",
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
  },
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-serializer-vue'
  ],
  testMatch: [
    '**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'
  ],
  testURL: 'http://localhost/'
}
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue but using `transformIgnorePatterns` doesn't appear to be doing anything. Could you share your Jest and Babel config?

Comment: @AndyPattenden Sure. I have edited the answer. If you have an issue caused by the compilation of a node module in jest, then you should be able to resolve it with `transformIgnorePatterns`. Be careful that the regex has to be precise or it won't work. It took me some attempts. In my config you can see how I do it for multiple node modules or just one.

Comment: thanks for that. That's the same as my config file but still wasn't working. I had my Babel config within `package.json` which Jest didn't seem to be detecting. As soon as I moved it into `babel.config.js` it all worked.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @FrancescoMussi's answer, after editing my jest.config.js, in case you get the error: jest-transform-stub not found, just install it. in my case I didn't had installed jest-transform-stub and jest-serializer-vue. after installing those my tests started working.

```
npm install --save-dev jest-serializer-vue
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-serializer-vue

and

```
npm install --save-dev jest-transform-stub
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-transform-stub

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @FrancescoMussi's solution, if it is still not working for you, make sure your Babel config is in the correct place as per the [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel)

I had moved my Babel config to `package.json` which Babel wasn't detecting due to Vue CLI installing Babel 7.  Moving Babel config back to `babel.config.js` resolved the issue for me.